# Install4j: Get the absolute path of the project file

Tags: install4j

I have the installer project with all the resources it uses added in my Gradle project (in path project_folder_path/install). But for some sql operations (which will run during the installation), I need to add some files located in other modules of my gradle project (for example in path project_folder_path/sql) to its distribution tree. So, is there any way to somehow get the file path of the .install4j file( or is there any variable existing) that I can manipulate later for finding the files required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative files are resolve relatively to the .install4j project file. So you don't need a variable for that location, just add relative paths to the distribution tree.

Comment: If I am not wrong, adding relative paths to the distribution tree will install the files to that path right? I have edited my question for a clearer understanding

Comment: I mean the source of the added files not where they are placed in the distribution tree. The source path has no influence on the installed location.

Comment: ok understood!! But the problem is, the project_folder_path (which is in the relative path) can vary when someone else is downloading the project from the repository.

Comment: Yes, the absolute project folder path can vary, but here you trying to resolve a directory relative to the location of the .install4j file, so the absolute path does not matter. Say the .install4j file is located in `[project folder]/install/installer.install4j`. Then the directory you're looking for in your question is referenced as `../sql`

Comment: ohk!! Now I got it! Thanks!!